# Problema com função ARRAY_SEARCH e Matriz no PHP

Tags: php, array, matriz, csv, data-manipulation

Olá, estou fazendo um código PHP que pega um arquivo CSV e estou separando o arquivo pela "coluna" Estados. Eu quero fazer uma matriz separando os estados que se repetem da seguinte forma:

```
array(array('SP',array('info1','info2','info3'),array('info1','info2','info3')),
    array('RJ',array('info1','info2','info3')),
    array('PE',array('info1','info2','info3'),array('info1','info2','info3'))
)
```

No código abaixo a função IF deveria estar verificando se a sigla já foi inserida no array. (Mas por algum motivo ela sempre resulta em falso).
No código que é rodado, apenas o else entra e o if sempre resulta em falso. Sendo que quando ocorre a repetição de uma sigla, o array(info1,info2,info3) deveria ser inserido no index de onde ocorreu a repetição da sigla. Conforme exemplo acima, onde em PE e SP ocorrerão duas repetições e RJ apenas uma.

```
<?php 
    $exp = file ('CSVs/exp2019_copy.csv');

    function processarDados(){
    
    global $exp;
    $tabelas = array();
    $linha = array();
    
        foreach($exp as $l){
            $linha = explode(";",$l);  //$linha armazena cada valor da linha como array.
            if(array_search($linha[5],$tabelas)!=false){
                $tabelas[array_search($linha[5],$tabelas)][] = array($linha[1],$linha[2],$linha[10]);
            }
            else{ 
                $tabelas[] = array($linha[5],array($linha[1],$linha[2],$linha[10]));
            }
        } print_r($tabelas);
    }
    processarDados();
?>
```

Na lógica `if(array_search($linha[5],$tabelas)!=false)` onde em `$linha[5]` se tem a string sigla e `$tabelas` é o array que deve receber a Sigla e os arrays com 3 informações.